# More than one insert operation in the same table at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, performance, informix

I will explain firstly what I do, then I will specify where is the problem.

My application gets an `XML file` from an authenticated user through (file uploader), then I map (I mean migrate) the data stored in the XML file to its equivalent one in my database.
I get the data from the XML file through `LINQ`.

- **My first question**

  Each element in
  the XML file has an equivalent entity
  in my database. What is the best and
  more performant  way to insert
  *more than one record* in a
  specific table and guarantee that if
  there is something wrong in the data, rollback the whole operation? 
  Is there some example of how to do
  this?  Do you have any suggestions concerning
  validating the XML data?
- **My second question:**

  In the first question, I talk about the
  the    (INSERT) operation.  If the
  user    changes some data in the XML
  file then I want to update my
  database with    the new data.  How should I
  do this?  Should I    compare each
  record, or try to    insert and, if that fails,
  then update this    record?

Comment: why down voted , if you don't understand the problem i will explain more

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it may come from the fact that you're asking two unrelated questions here. It would be better to break them up into individual questions, since the answer to one has nothing to do with the answer to the other.

Comment: yeah but i face the two problems in the same applicaion, and i wanna to explain the whole problem..hmmm never mind

Comment: Just because your questions are part of the same application does not mean that they are actually related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> each element in the XML file has an
>   equivalent entity in my database. What
>   is the best and more performance way
>   to insert more than one record in a
>   specific table .and guarantee if there
>   is some thing wrong in the data ,
>   rollback the whole operation .please
>   if there is some sample to do this.and
>   any suggestions concerning validating
>   the XML data.

The simple answer here is: use a transaction. The point of transactions is to provide you with a mechanism whereby you can execute multiple commands, then either commit them as a single unit of work or roll them back completely so that the database is left in a state as if your operations had never taken place.

> in the first one i talk about the the
>   (INSERT) operation, if the user change
>   some data in the XML file then i wanna
>   to update my database with the new
>   data.how to o this .should i compare
>   each record . or try to insert if fail
>   then update this record?.

The try-error-different retry pattern is not a desirable one if it can be easily avoided. Your SQL should either use a statement that is designed to conditionally insert or update depending on existing data (such as the SQL Server `MERGE` command; I don't have Informix experience so I can't speak to what it supports or if `MERGE` is ANSI SQL), or you should do this conditional logic yourself within the SQL.

Comment: thanks a lot , i think about transaction but i don't know the number of (insert) operation every time. how to do this.

Comment: @just_name: That's not a problem. You can execute as many operations as you want within a transaction. You begin the transaction, execute your commands (whatever and how many there are), then either commit or rollback the transaction.

Comment: hmmm, thanks ,this is not the problem , i think how to make a transaction method so general to be used in my application.. every time i don't know how many records i will insert in each entity .so i need a method to insert more than one record with this guarantee .write one and use many.

Comment: @just_name: It seems that either you aren't understanding me or I'm not understanding you; transactions are database objects and are associated with your connection, so you are free to have the lifetime of a transaction span multiple functions as long as all of the operations take place on the same connection.

Comment: i mean . i know how to write a transaction. but i need a a method idea  in c#  to make a transaction with the number of records needed to be inserted in specific table.

Comment: i mean by method ----> function ,excuse me if i can't explain clearly. my English isn't that good.

Comment: @just_name: You don't need a method or function in C# to create your transaction, as you should be using a construct that's already there (whether that's ADO.NET, Entity Framework, etc.). Perhaps you could provide an example of what you're talking about? Your question is not at all clear, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use an informix stored procedure for this.
This will allow you to include exception handling for dealing with bad data.

You can then load all your entities into a temp table first, say t_work, if there is a data issue then drop the table and raise an excpetion.

```
BEGIN -- Start Exception Handling
  ON EXCEPTION SET esql, eisam

  DROP TABLE t_work;
  RAISE EXCEPTION esql, eisam; -- rethrow the exception
  END EXCEPTION

    -- << Your logic here>>
```

See here for more details: http://www.pacs.tju.edu/informix/answers/english/docs/dbdk/infoshelf/sqlt/14.toc.html#540217